# MYSQL : writing a query where a column is the result of a boolean expression

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table where i have columns such as:

```
deposit_received
paperwork_received
preferred_physician
preferred_physician_phone
```

One of the views that we use this data involves displaying whether there is any of this data missing.  I can arrange this trivially in PHP, but I'd rather do it in MySQL (it leverages a framework's sort by feature if I can do it in MySQL.

So essentially, I need to write a query that returns:

```
col1 | col2 | ... | (deposit_received == true && paperwork_received == true && preferred_physician != null && preferred_physician_phone != null)
```

I've looked at some of the functions you can use, but I can't wrap my head around it.

Thanks in advance!
Rob

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can always just write the query:

```
SELECT col1, col2,
    (deposit_received
    AND paperwork_received 
    AND preferred_physician IS NOT NULL
    AND preferred_physician_phone IS NOT NULL)
  AS Result
FROM tableName
```

The parentheses are optional, however it improves readability.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the COALESCE function to deal with the NULLs e.g. The function 'COALESCE' can simplify working with null values. For example, to treat null as zero, you can use:

```
select COALESCE(colname,0) from table where COALESCE(colname,0) > 1;
```